# How to force a refresh of a custom console component

Tags: service-cloud-console, console, custom-console-components

When a primary tab is refreshed, it refreshes all of it's subtabs and application-level custom components. It's possible to prevent the refresh of one of the application-level custom components by overriding it's refresh behavior:

```
sforce.console.onEnclosingTabRefresh(function() {
  // Whatever you put in here will be run when the page refreshes
});
```

We have a situation where in general we want to prevent the application-level custom component from refreshing, but sometimes we want to let it force it's own refresh.

**Doesn't work:**

A typical Javascript refresh will not really update the page since it won't re-run the controller initialization:

```
location.reload();
```

**Works, but generates errors:**

```
location = "/apex/{!$CurrentPage.Name}?id={!$CurrentPage.parameters.id}&isdtp=vw"
```

This Javascript command works, but generates console errors because it doesn't load the console-specific HTML that wraps the visualforce page.

**How can I force the refresh of a console component?**

I don't see any methods available in the Console Integration guide to force the refresh of a console component; the methods to refresh subtabs won't work since console components don't have that kind of ID.